# Spring component depends on the configuration which load props from application.properties but props are not loaded

Tags: spring, frameworks, components, javabeans, autowired

I have some difficulties and I can't realize how to let it work because of lack of knowledge in Spring framework.
What I'm trying to do is pretty simple. I want to use injected **AppProperties** in **RestTemplateComponent** **constuctor** or **getRestTemplate** method but all props are null.
I think I understand why.. it's because **RestTemplateComponent**  by the order was loaded first and that's why **AppProperties** props are null.

Is it possible some how to tell to Spring to load AppProperties first in order to use it in RestTemplateComponent.

By the way problem occurs only on start there is no any problem when I inject it in controller and during request use these objects.

**application.properties**

```
integration.url=http://...
```

```
@Configuration
@ConstructorBinding
@ConfigurationProperties("integration")
public class AppProperties {
    private String url;

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }
}
```

```
@Component
public class RestTemplateComponent {
    private final AppProperties appProperties;

    public RestTemplateComponent(AppProperties appProperties) {
        this.appProperties = appProperties;
    }

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate getRestTemplate() {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        //Custom authorization
        return restTemplate;
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like you are missing an `@Autowired` on your constructor of `RestTemplateComponent`

Comment: Annotation is not required starting from some new version of Spring. I use 2.2.3 which is not require it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, finally I did it work by adding annotation **@PropertySource({"classpath:application.properties"})** within my AppProperties class and then when I try to autowire AppProperties in SpringBootApplication I see in debug that props are initialized.